# 'request' module not pinging web pages correctly when they are contained in list

Tags: list, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using the request module to see if items in a list of words are an article at https://www.britannica.com. My current code is:

```
import requests

words = ['no', 'yes', 'thermodynamics', 'london', 'Max-Factor', 'be']

for word in words:
    request = requests.head('https://www.britannica.com/topic/' + word.lower())
    if request.status_code == 200:
        print(">EXISTS")
        print('https://www.britannica.com/topic/' + word.lower())
        print("<")
    else:
        print(">DOESNT EXIST")
        print('https://www.britannica.com/topic/' + word.lower())
        print("<")
```

'Be' is the only string that prints 'EXIST', but 'thermodynamics', 'london', and 'Max-Factor' also exists and the program prints 'DOESNT EXIST'. If I do the operation on thermodynamics alone, it correctly prints 'EXISTS'. What is the reason and possible work-around for the discrepancy? Possibly the loading times of the various webpages ('Be' having the smallest)?

Comment: How about you indent your `if..else` block under the `for` loop?

Comment: @zwer fixed, now is the same as original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, britanica.com uses redirects, probably for load balancing, so you'll often get status `301` instead of `200`. The `requests` module can follow on redirects if you use:

```
request = requests.head('https://www.britannica.com/topic/' + word.lower(),
                        allow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: It may also be worth noting that `allow_redirects` is normally defaulted to `True`, but `head` defaults to `False`